# How do workshop adjacency bonuses work?

Tags: xcom-2

Apparently workshops can now staff adjacent facilities with "unique GREMLIN drones", but how exactly does it work? Do facilities that share a corner count as adjacent, or is it only for facilities that share an edge? Can 2 adjacent workshops staff each other? How do different facilities benefit from an adjacent workshop, and are there any that don't benefit at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only adjacency bonuses are exactly like they were in the previous game: directly vertical and directly horizontal. For this reason, you'll want to build any workshops in the middle column of the base, rather than on one of the edges.

Once you've staffed a workshop, you gain access to staff those adjacent rooms with 2 Gremlins that are themselves engineers. This will net you once bonus engineer per workshop.

Obviously, this means that any adjacent facility that can't use engineers (Labs, for instance) will never benefit from workshops.

Comment: What facilities accept engineers as staff? How many engineers can you assign to a single workshop? How many GREMLINs does a workshop give to adjact facilities? Does having more adjact facilities means each facility gets fewer GREMLINs, or does each facility get the full number of GREMLINs the workshop produces?

Comment: @kotekzot You get 2 Gremlins, but you need 1 Engineer to staff the facility, so you Net 1 Engineer. I'll update my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: Are the adjacency bonuses purely "have an engineer", or are there other benefits as well?

Comment: @Kexlox As far as I can tell, they're purely "have an engineer".

Comment: Couldn't you upgrade the workshop so you get more gremlins?

Comment: Is it possible to build a second workshop?

Comment: the gremlins can also be used to clear and build. I believe you only get one workshop but if you go the the build facilities option in the engineering menu you can remove built things with the red x and rebuild them at cost

Comment: @robbie_c No, you are limited to 1 workshop.